# Can not play local rtsp URL using FFmpeg in iOS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `FFmpeg` for stream `rtsp` URL in iOS.
I am trying to stream a local url but my app is failed to open url 
`avformat_open_input` method always return -5

I have played the same url `rtsp://172.16.1.226:5544/1` on VLC media player on my iPhone and macbook it works on both.

After few research i have found there is some problem with `rtsp_transport`

I was using `av_dict_set(&serverOpt, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);` for the server configuration while opening url and the result is can not open feed.

When I changed it to `av_dict_set(&serverOpt, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 1);`
I am able to open url successfully but I continuously getting error rtsp 1 missing packet and so on.

Can anybody help what should be the right configuration while opening a local `rtsp url` using `ffmpeg`.
Should i need to update  `av_dict_set(&serverOpt, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 1)`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use UDP means `av_dict_set(&serverOpt, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 0)` in your code it will work.

You can also skip this step. I am playing local and remote both RTSP URL and setting nothing.

Direct open the URL using `avformat_open_input` without specify the `rtsp_transport`.